What would be the difference in processing/usage for these two tomato products?
Regarding the two tomato products in the attached pictures, I believe
A) the juice has been cooked boiled in water, perhaps boiled off to make a concentrated taste, and then strained of remaining solids.
B) the purée has been boiled and strained like the juice, it then is continually boiled off until no water remains given a strong taste and past like thickness,
I’m not sure if this is correct, based on my understanding the only difference is remaining water content?  If so would continue to boil the juice lead it to become the same as the purée?
Please clarify.
Also where might it be better to use the juice over the purée?  I imagine as the juice has a lot of water it’s not too concentrated and you can drink more getting more nutrients and use it in soups, stews or as a sauce whereas the purée is too concentrated in small amounts so wouldn’t be suitable however a quick google search says the paste/purée is used to thicken sauces as well as give flavour to stews and soups but wouldn’t the juice be better for this purpose to get a more all around taste?
Thanks



I've never heard of 'pressed juice', but I would expect it to be strained like cloudy apple juice (what the US calls apple cider).  "Tomato purée" is called "Tomato paste" in the US, so see  https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/86089/67 .  (and be warned that the US also has a 'tomato purée' which is not cooked down to concentrate it)

tomato juice is not normally cooked at all. Just squeezed out and separated somewhat from the solids. The puree will be cooked and probably not strained at all, just, well, pureed.

Tomato juice is for drinking (as the glass indicates). The very concentrated purée/paste sold in tubes is for flavouring cooked dishes.
